# Logic error trying to filter a django queryset with Q objects

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model that has separate DateExpired and TimeExpired fields:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    date_expired = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    time_expired = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

How expiry works for a Thing:

1. If `date_expired` and `time_expired` are `null`: thing never expires
2. If `date_expired exists`, but time_expired is `null`: thing expires after the date
3. If `date_expired` and `time_expired` exist: thing expires on that date, after the time
4. If only `time_expired` exists: thing expires after the time (daily, so would become not expired again at midnight when time = 00:00:00)

I want to get a queryset containing all Things that are NOT expired.  Currently, I can successfully capture 1,2, and 4, with this code:

```
def not_expired(self):
    qs_ = self.filter( Q(date_expired = None) | Q(date_expired__gte = datetime.now) )
    return qs.exclude( Q(date_expired = None) & Q(time_expired__lt = datetime.now) )
```

but I can't figure out how to add requirement #3.  Here is what I have:

```
def not_expired(self):
    qs = self.filter( Q(date_expired = None) | Q(date_expired__gte = datetime.now) )
    qs = qs.exclude( Q(date_expired = datetime.now) & Q(time_expired__gt = datetime.now ))
    return qs.exclude( Q(date_expired = None) & Q(time_expired__lt = datetime.now) )
```

But there is something wrong there because it doesn't resolve #3.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, things that are not expired are those where:

1. Either date_expired is > today and time_expired is None
2. Either date_expired is None and time_expired > Now
3. Either date_expired > today and time_expired > Now
4. Either date_expired and time_expired is None

If so, I believe this should get you what you are after:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()

qs.filter((Q(date_expired__gt=now.date()) & Q(time_expired = None)) |
          (Q(time_expired__gt=now) & Q(date_expired=None)) |
          (Q(date_expired__gt=now.date()) & Q(time_expired__gt=now)) |
          (Q(time_expired=None) & Q(date_expired=None)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think this will work;

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()

qs.filter( Q(date_expired__isnull=True, time_expired__isnull=True) | Q(date_expired__lte=now.date(), time_expired__isnull=True) | Q(date_expired__isnull=False, time_expired__isnull=False,date_expired__lte=now.date(), time_expired__lt=now.time()) |  Q(date_expired__isnull=True, time_expired__lt=now.time()))
```

#3 solution

```
qs.filter(Q(date_expired__isnull=False, time_expired__isnull=False,date_expired__lte=now.date(), time_expired__lt=now.time()))
```